# Install GNOME in freebsd

Tags: gnome, freebsd

I'm new to FreeBSD it comes with a CLI mode not a graphical interface. How can I install GNOME in FreeBSD. Can I install GNOME by downloading its package from a different machine if its possible and also what is the size of GNOME v 2.0.

Comment: It is not easy to keep dependency. You can check where are the packages downloaded located in your file system first. And see what packages are needed.

Comment: Try http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/x11-wm.html and see the failure information about what are supposed to download.

Comment: Ya I have seen that but the problem is my internet connection is slow so I was thinking is it possible to download the package from somewhere else.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using Ubuntu. So I recommend you to see where are the cache packages. Then find out what packages are needed.

Comment: http://149.20.54.209/showthread.php?p=94896

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/334934/freebsd-ports-how-can-i-see-all-dependencies-for-a-port-and-all-subdependencie

Comment: Note that GNOME **2.0** was released [11 years ago](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/02/06/26/1813231/gnome-20-released), in June 2002. Something tells me that is not the version you want to install.

Comment: I didnt knew that but I think ver 3.0 is still under development and not stable.

Comment: GNOME 3.0 was released in April 2011 and they are now up to version 3.8. [Check Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME#Versions). Sure it's still under development, but so is the FreeBSD kernel (or so one would hope). And if you meant GNOME **2.x** you should say that rather than 2.0 specifically.

Comment: ohk. Ya then I should opt for the version 3.

Answer (score 2):

The ports are available on multiple servers around the world and you should check [the handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/index.html) for that list. Also, there is a "fastest server" port that will locate that for you. You can check for size and other information before doing anything by looking at http://freshports.org/.

[There is a description for installing Gnome in the handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/x11-wm.html). Follow that.